# How do I pass a struct from a class to a winform

Tags: c#

I tried to do something like this:

```
        m_mystruct = (Form1.mystruct)m_myclass.mystruct;
```

where both structs have same definition.

C# doesn't want to do the cast.

Update: instead of why, I modify my question

How do I pass a struct from a class to a winform ?

Comment: so what :) I don't ask questions because I want to improve indicators but because I need answer to them. Key Process Indictator is a proxy which doesn't always reflect the true reality.

Comment: I'm asking a lot of questions because I'm working on many languages and platforms.

Comment: It indicates to potential answerers that you can't be bothered to accept answers.

Comment: It means the indicators are not not well designed because I have always accepted answers you can see by yourself in history.

Comment: Well because they are gurus, I'm not otherwise I would answer questions. My qyestions are very beginner's question so sorry i'm not good enough :)

Comment: What Dinah is talking about is your character, not your knowledge or expertise.

Comment: What's my character has to do with my questions ?!!! You don't even know me that's funny !

Comment: If a person shows themselves to be more self-centered than generous and caring in one aspect then it is fair to comment on that one aspect.  You might be different when it comes to other parts of your life but no one is commenting on how you are overall.  We are just talking about how you act on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are defined in two separate places then they are actually two different types.

You could define explicit and implicit operators to convert between the two. It might look like this.

```
public struct Foo
{
    public int Value;

    public static explicit operator Bar(Foo source)
    {
        var destination = new Bar();
        destination.Value = source.Value;
        return destination;
    }
}

public struct Bar
{
    public int Value;

    public static explicit operator Foo(Bar source)
    {
        var destination = new Foo();
        destination.Value = source.Value;
        return destination;
    }
}
```

Think about whether you really need two different declarations. But, whatever you decide do not do the following unless you absolutely have no other choice. It could go wrong in so many different ways.

```
Foo f = new Foo();
IntPtr pf = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(f));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(f, pf, false);
Bar b = (Bar)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pf, typeof(Bar));
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pf);
```

or

```
unsafe
{
  Foo f = new Foo();
  Bar b = *(Bar*)&f;
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you, I didn't expect such simple question would need such complicated code.

Comment: Are you kidding me?  It doesn't require complicated code.  In fact, the obvious solution requires less code than you started with.  If you just used a single struct definition to start with, none of this would be a problem.

Answer (score 6):

Having the "same definition" doesn't make them the same type.

In fact, if there are two definitions, then they are two different types.

Comment: sure but that's why I cast. My question is why cast doesn't work.

Comment: Casting doesn't work that way. Is that the reason for the downvote?

Comment: Casting is not allowed between different types unless there is a conversion defined.

Answer (score 3):

Because, while the have the same definition, they are not related in any way.

If you want to be able to cast between the two types, you have to define the [explicit/implicit conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65ht46ht(v=VS.90).aspx).

Comment: That article has a nice link that user310291 could probably use ("How to: Implement User-Defined Conversions Between Structs (C# Programming Guide)

Answer (score 0):

They are basically different types!

Comment: Not just basically.  Technically and completely.

Comment: Well that I know :) that is not my question.

Comment: But it is the answer to your question.  Unrelated types with no conversion defined can not be cast to each other.

Comment: OK but that doesn't SOLVE my problem: how do I pass a struct from a class to a winform :)

Comment: Well the obvious solution is to use the same struct.

Comment: can you map this struct into an object that both know about and pass it around?

Comment: What if they are in different .net modules ?

Comment: @user310291: You can use a struct in Assembly B that's declared in Assembly A if that's your question.